# How to retreive data from Firebase with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve some data from Firebase using JavaScript, but I have a problem. I can't get the items of my child "Usuarios". 
[This is how my database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwrQl.png)

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Usuarios");
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    var name = snap.child("Nombre").val();
    var email `enter code here`= snap.child("Apellido").val();
    $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td><td><button>Remove</button></td></tr>");
});
```

Comment: From what i see in your database structure you have a `netflixfirebase-568e8` as a child node in your  `netflixfirebase-568e8` database. Your code would reference the first level children in your database and "Usuarios" is a second level child

Comment: I´ve tried this, but I get null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve got a solution, I added the function "childSnapshot"to the "Snapchot" that I already had.I checked each element (that is an Object) and took the properties they contained.

The code here:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref ().child("Usuarios/");
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        var keystl = Object.keys(childData);
        console.log(childData);
        console.log(keystl);
        for (var i = 0; i < keystl.length; i++)
        {
            var k = keystl[i];
            var nombre = childData[k].Nombre;
            var apellido = childData[k].Apellido;
            console.log(nombre, apellido);
              $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + nombre + "</td><td>" + apellido + "</td><td><button>Remove</button></td></tr>");

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

what @hazelcodes said, It would look something like this

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("netflixfirebase-568e8/Usuarios");
```

Comment: When I try this I get null

Comment: The error is as a result of this line `var name = snap.child("Nombre").val();`. You can see that "Nombre" is not a direct child of "Usuarios". It's the child of a child "so to speak".